# Checking if some elements of a cell array are identical?

Tags: matlab

Is there an easy way that you can check if all elements in a row or column or any of the diagonals are the same thing?

```
a={'o','','o';
   'x','o','o';
   'x','o','o'}
```

How can I check if all elements in a row or column or any of the diagonals are the same thing?

Comment: What is the size (dimensions) of your cell array? give an example with desired results!

Comment: @SanthanSalai: I have added an example now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can employ [`isequal`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isequal.html) and use the fact that it can accept multiple arguments and indexing cell arrays can create comma-separated lists:

for second row:

```
>> isequal(a{2,:})
ans =
     0
```

for third column:

```
>> isequal(a{:,3})
ans =
     1
```

for diagonal:

```
>> isequal(a{logical(eye(size(a)))})
ans =
     1
```

for anti-diagonal:

```
>> isequal(a{flipud(logical(eye(size(a))))})
ans =
     0
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach with `unique`, few `diff`'s and combinations of `any, all` -

```
%// Tag each cell element based on their uniqueness among other cells
[~,~,idx] = unique(a)
ar = reshape(idx,size(a))

%// Perform checks along columns, rows, diagonals and anti-diagonals
col_check = any(all(diff(ar,[],1)==0,1))
row_check = any(all(diff(ar,[],2)==0,2))
diag_check = all(diff(ar(eye(3)==1))==0)
antidiag_check = all(diff(ar(fliplr(eye(3))==1))==0)

%// Finally check if any of the checks are true for the final output
out = col_check | row_check | diag_check | antidiag_check
```

Sample run -

```
a = 
    'x'    ''     'o'    'o'
    ''     'o'    'o'    'o'
    'o'    'o'    'o'    'x'
    'o'    'o'    'o'    'o'
col_check =
     1
row_check =
     1
diag_check =
     0
antidiag_check =
     0
out =
     1
```